# Placing labels at some distance from line when using callout

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to label my lines, but I want to place the labels so that they don't overlap with the line, and preferably even with some distance to the line. I want have added callouts to show what label corresponds to what line.

I have tried a bunch of different settings in the Label menu, but I haven't had luck yet. I did enable "Features act as obstacles".

The screenshot below shows what it looks like now. The callout can be seen on #32.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `Parallel` mode for lableing, set allowed postions to `Above line` and set an appropriate distance. See the result:

[image]

Comment: Interestingly I did get it to work with "parallel", but in my case making them parallel would make it less reader friendly. I am tweaking these thing in order to make it as reader friendly as possible.

Answer (score -1):

Try entering the 'placement' editing when in the label settings, that should do the trick for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I honestly think I tried all settings under "Placement", with no luck. Well except Geometry Generator, which could perhaps do it, but that is a complex solution which requires that I learn about it first. Could you please be more specific?